# Why does code work different based on vars or generators inside a set?

Tags: python, set, generator

The goal is to find out the amount of numbers of a**b, where 2<=a,b<=100. Task is simple and I found the answer, but I don't quit understand why this works fine:

```
def count():
   return len(set(a**b for a in range(2,101) for b in range(2,101)))
```

But this goes wrong:

```
def count():
    a = (i for i in range(2,101))
    b = (i for i in range(2,101))
    return len(set(i**j for i in a for j in b))
```

Even this works fine (based on the second func): `return len(set(i**j for i in a for j in range(2, 101)))`

But change the first var to a generator and do the opposite with the next one, and it goes wrong:
`return len(set(i**j for i in range(2, 101) for j in a))`

 Really wanted to figure out this on my own, but I just don't know what's wrong

Comment: `a` and `b` are generator expressions -- `b` gets exhausted on the first inner loop completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ddejohn gave you a very short answer, so I will expand on it.

The behavior of Python's generators is a bit strange at first. Here is a simple example :

```py
my_generator = (i for i in range(3))  # 0 to 2 included
print(next(my_generator))  # 0
print(next(my_generator))  # 1
print(next(my_generator))  # 2
print(next(my_generator))  # StopIteration raised
```

The generator will provide its values, then raise a `StopIteration` exception.

Subsequent calls to `next` when the generator is exhausted will continue to raise the `StopIteration` exception.
It means that we can not loop twice over a generator, here is an example :

```py
my_generator = (i for i in range(3))  # 0 to 2 included
for letter in ('a', 'b'):
    print(letter)
    for num in my_generator:
        print(num)
    print("end")
```

```
a
0
1
2
end
b
end
```

For the first letter, we looped on the generator values until it raised a `StopIteration` which indicated the `for` loop to stop. For the second letter, the generator immediately raised `StopIteration` so the loop made no iteration at all.

That's by design : generator are meant to be used only once, they generate values until they are exhausted.

Coming back to your code, I transformed your generator `i**j for i in a for j in b` into two loops to make it simpler to print :

```
def count():
    a = (i for i in range(2,101))
    b = (i for i in range(2,101))
    for i in a:
        print(f"outer loop {i=}")
        for j in b:
            print(f"  inner loop {j=}")
count()
```

```
outer loop i=2
  inner loop j=2
  inner loop j=3
  inner loop j=4
  [...]
  inner loop j=99
  inner loop j=100
outer loop i=3
outer loop i=4
outer loop i=5
outer loop i=6
[...]
outer loop i=98
outer loop i=99
outer loop i=100
```

You can see that the first iteration for `i` did was expected, but not the other ones, because the `j` generator was already exhausted.

Here are two ways to fix that problem :

- not using a generator (because here you only have ~100 values, a generator is not required)

  ```py
  def count():
      a = (i for i in range(2,101))
      b = tuple(i for i in range(2,101))
      #   ^^^^^
      for i in a:
          print(f"outer loop {i=}")
          for j in b:
              print(f"  inner loop {j=}")
  count()
  ```
- or building a new generator for each outer-iteration :

  ```py
  def count():
      a = (i for i in range(2,101))
      # not here
      for i in a:
          print(f"outer loop {i=}")
          # but here :
          b = (i for i in range(2,101))
          for j in b:
              print(f"  inner loop {j=}")
  count()
  ```

The second solution is what is done implicitly in the version of your code that works (`a**b for a in range(2,101) for b in range(2,101)`) : a new `range` object is created at each iteration of `a`.

I hope it's clearer now.

---

Nitpick : `(i for i in range(2,101))` is pretty much equivalent to simply `range(2,101)` because the `range` object is already lazy, so wrapping it in an explicit generator adds nothing.